# Could somebody explain this error to me?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I just got the following error and I have no idea what to make of it.

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Timer.__bootstrap of <Timer(Thread-3, stopped -1234564240)>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 525, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 565, in __bootstrap_inner
    (self.name, _format_exc()))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/traceback.py", line 241, in format_exc
    return ''.join(format_exception(etype, value, tb, limit))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/traceback.py", line 141, in format_exception
    list = list + format_tb(tb, limit)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/traceback.py", line 76, in format_tb
    return format_list(extract_tb(tb, limit))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/traceback.py", line 101, in extract_tb
    line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno, f.f_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/linecache.py", line 14, in getline
    lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/linecache.py", line 40, in getlines
    return updatecache(filename, module_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/linecache.py", line 133, in updatecache
    lines = fp.readlines()
MemoryError
```

Relevant code (although I'm not sure if it's actually relevant - it's just the only part of my code that is in any way mentioned by the exception):

```
class Timer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, interval, callback, limit=0, args=[], kwargs={}):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.interval = interval / 1000.0
        self.callback = callback
        self.limit = limit
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.iterations = 0
        self._stop = threading.Event()

    def restart(self):
        self.iterations = 0
        self._stop.clear()
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while not self._stop.wait(self.interval):
            self.callback(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            self.iterations += 1
            if self.limit > 0 and self.iterations >= self.limit:
                break

    def stop(self):
        self._stop.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop.isSet()
```

I think it was around this time that the server on which I was running the code was sort of falling apart - was this just a symptom, or was it indicative of problems with my code somewhere else?
Mostly, though, I just want to know what the hell this means, I can probably figure out the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ran out of memory. From the [python docs on exceptions](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html):

> exception MemoryError
>
> Raised when an operation runs out of memory but
>   the situation may still be rescued (by deleting some objects). The
>   associated value is a string indicating what kind of (internal)
>   operation ran out of memory. Note that because of the underlying
>   memory management architecture (C’s malloc() function), the
>   interpreter may not always be able to completely recover from this
>   situation; it nevertheless raises an exception so that a stack
>   traceback can be printed, in case a run-away program was the cause.

So you either:

- Ran out of system memory (you filled up all your physical RAM, and all of your pagefile.) This is entirely possible to do if you had a runaway loop creating lots of data very fast.
- You ran into the 2GB per-process RAM limit.

Note that Python on *32-bit* systems has a 2G memory limit regardless of how much physical ram you have, or if PAE is enabled. This isn't Python-specific - it's an operating system limitation.

It probably wasn't the `Timer` class that caused the problem - it's just that you *happened* to run out of memory while doing something with a `Timer`.

Comment: Funny that my Python doesn't know about that - it bailed out on 2,5 GB. I thought the limit was at 3 GiB, but somehow it came earlier here...

Comment: @glglgl: I may be missing a "win32" in my statements somewhere. I'm not crystal clear on the per-process memory limits in every OS - I just know that there *are* limits and that you can run into them if you're not careful. ;)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html)...

```
exception MemoryError
    Raised when an operation runs out of memory but the situation may still be rescued
    (by deleting some objects). The associated value is a string indicating what kind
    of (internal) operation ran out of memory. Note that because of the underlying
    memory management architecture (C’s malloc() function), the interpreter may not
    always be able to completely recover from this situation; it nevertheless raises
    an exception so that a stack traceback can be printed, in case a run-away program
    was the cause.
```

Comment: Beat me by 40 seconds, you rascal. ;)